# Can this be made more functional?

Tags: f#

Just starting out with f#, I come OO C# background and I have the following code that reads a text file of uk postscodes, it then hits an api end point with post codes, I test the result to see if post is valid or not:

```
let postCodeFile = "c:\\tmp\\randomPostCodes.txt"

let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)

let lines = readLines postCodeFile

let postCodeValidDaterUrl = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/"

let validatePostCode postCode =
            Request.createUrl Get (postCodeValidDaterUrl + postCode)
            |> getResponse
            |> run

let translateResponse response = 
                                match response.statusCode with
                                | 200 -> true
                                | _ -> false

let validPostCode = validatePostCode >> translateResponse

lines |> Seq.iter(fun x -> validPostCode(x) |> printfn "%s-%b" x)
```

Any suggestions on making it more functional?

Comment: Side-effects in, side-effects out.  Is there really any good reason to make this more "functional," given that it is procedural by nature?

Comment: ah kk good point there, as I say just starting out and experimenting

Answer (score 4):

#### Critique / code review

You've already made this about as functional as it can be. I'll go through your code and explain why your decisions were good, and in a few cases, where you could make minor improvements.

```
let postCodeFile = "c:\\tmp\\randomPostCodes.txt"
```

Good to have this as a named variable; in real code, this would of course be a parameter to the script or a function parameter. So having it as a named variable is useful.

```
let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath)
```

This function isn't strictly necessary; since `System.IO.File.ReadLines` takes a single parameter, you would be able to pipe into it (e.g., `postCodeFile |> System.IO.File.ReadLines |> Seq.iter(...)`. But I like the shorter name, so I'd probably write it this way as well.

```
let lines = readLines postCodeFile
```

I'd probably leave off creating the `lines` name, and instead do `postCodeFile |> readLines |> Seq.iter (...)` in the last line of your code. There's nothing inherently *wrong* with the way you've done it, but you don't use the `lines` variable anywhere else so there's no real reason to give it a name. F#'s pipes allow you to skip naming your intermediate steps.

```
let postCodeValidDaterUrl = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/"
```

Again, good to give this a name so that you can turn it into a parameter or a config file variable later. Only thing I see here that could be improved is the spelling: `ValidDater` should have been `Validator`.

```
let validatePostCode postCode =
            Request.createUrl Get (postCodeValidDaterUrl + postCode)
            |> getResponse
            |> run
```

Looks good.

```
let translateResponse response = 
                                match response.statusCode with
                                | 200 -> true
                                | _ -> false
```

Could be simpler: `let translateResponse response = (response.statusCode = 200)`. But the `match` expression lets you expand it later if you have an API that could return other status codes, like 204, to indicate success as well. I'd probably go with the simpler comparison here, and add the `match` statement only if it's needed.

```
let validPostCode = validatePostCode >> translateResponse
```

Nice.

```
lines |> Seq.iter(fun x -> validPostCode(x) |> printfn "%s-%b" x)
```

As I mentioned earlier, `lines` is an intermediate step, so I'd probably change this to `postCodeFile |> readLines |> Seq.iter (...)` since that allows you to skip giving names to your intermediate steps.

#### Why this is good

Two things you did well here:

1. You wrote each function to do just one thing, and composed functions together to create larger "building blocks" of code. E.g., `validatePostCode` just sends off a request, and a different function decides whether the response indicates a valid code. This is good.
2. You separated (as much as you could) your I/O from your business logic. Specifically, the part of the code that validates the post codes doesn't try to read them in, or write out the results; it just says "Is this valid, or not?" That means that if you later need to swap out the API you call, or if you can do some internal checking on post codes that doesn't need to go hit the outside world, you can swap that out easily later. It's usually good practice to write your code in "layers", with I/O as the "outside" layer of your code, validation just "inside" the I/O layer, and then business logic inside the validation layer — so that your business-logic code can trust that it has received only valid data. You don't have any business logic in this simple example, but you have the I/O and validation layers properly separated. Well done.

Comment: some useful take aways there many thanks, i am currently working through get programming with f# and domain modelling made functional. need to get on do something a bit more complicated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the aim here should be to make the code "more functional". Being functional is not an inherent value. In F#, it makes sense to keep the core of your logic functional, but if you are doing a lot of I/O, then it makes sense to follow more imperative style.

My version of your code would look like this (somewhat overlapping with some suggestions by @rmunn):

```
let postCodeFile = "c:\\tmp\\randomPostCodes.txt"
let postCodeValidDaterUrl = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/"

let lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(postCodeFile)

let validatePostCode postCode =
    Request.createUrl Get (postCodeValidDaterUrl + postCode)
    |> getResponse
    |> run

let translateResponse response = 
    response.statusCode = 200

for line in lines do
    let valid = translateResponse (validatePostCode line) 
    printfn "%s-%b" line valid
```

My changes are:

- I removed the `readLines` helper and just call `File.ReadLines` directly. There is no need to introduce F# alias for .NET methods if it does not serve some greater purpose like providing a more F#-friendly API that is reused in multiple places.
- Like @rmunn, I replaced the `match` with `response.statusCode = 200`. I only use `match` when I need to bind new variables as part of matching. When just testing Boolean conditions, I think `if` is better.
- I replaced your composed function and `Seq.iter` with a normal `for` loop. The code is imperative anyway, so I do not see why you wouldn't want to use a built-in language construct. I eliminated `validPostCode` because you're only using the composed function in one place, so introducing it does not simplify code.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my style, it is not necessarily more functional or better:

```
open System.IO

let postCodeFile          = "c:\\tmp\\randomPostCodes.txt"
let postCodeValidDaterUrl = "https://api.postcodes.io/postcodes/"

let validatePostCode postCode =
    Request.createUrl Get (postCodeValidDaterUrl + postCode)
    |> getResponse
    |> run
    |> fun response -> response.statusCode = 200    

File.ReadLines postCodeFile
|> Seq.iter (fun code -> validatePostCode code |> printfn "%s-%b" code )
```